# Load another HTML file inside dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `index.html` and have another html file with a lot of text.

Now I don't want to paste this bunch of codes into my `index.html`.
I don't want to make it larger, the other file is not always called only if the button is clicked.

How do I get the div area from `another_file.html` ?

```
$("#buttonClick").on("click",function(evt) {
    $("#load-another-file").dialog({});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [jQuery's $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), which is a way of loading data without refreshing the page:

```
$("#buttonClick").on("click",function(evt) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'another_file.html',
        success: function(data){ // You received the data
            $("#load-another-file").html(data).dialog("open");
        }
    });
});
```

**Note**: for this to work, you might have to put your files on a server (even a local one), because some browsers don't allow Ajax requests on local files for security reasons (e.g. Google Chrome).

Comment: I do get the data on my console.log but I can't get the data inside the `dialog()` with `dialog(data)`

Comment: @Inna I might have made a mistake (did not read the [`$.dialog`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) documentation). I updated my answer, try it and tell me if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [`jquery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), load perform a server call and fetchs the `HTML` returned in your element.

```
$("#buttonClick").on("click",function(evt) {
    $("#load-another-file").dialog().load("another_file.html");
});
```